# libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, postgis

I am trying to import openstreetmap into postgresql,
when I executed the command CREATE EXTENSION postgis; it returned this error,

> ERROR:  could not load library
>   "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/rtpostgis-2.2.so": /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1:
>   undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

Does anyone has an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like one of the requirements for GDAL is not installed. Does `ldd /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1` show any problems?

Comment: I see no errors it is just listing dependencies :

**linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffde6dfb000)
 libarmadillo.so.6 => /usr/lib/libarmadillo.so.6 (0x00007f56705f6000)
 libproj.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.9 (0x00007f567039b000)
 libpoppler.so.58 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler.so.58 (0x00007f566ff1c000)
 libfreexl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreexl.so.1 (0x00007f566fd13000)**

Comment: Then maybe PostGIS was build with a different GDAL library than you have installed.

Comment: yes I think you hit the point, I installed another version of GDAL, now the error is mentioning a new line number : **could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/rtpostgis-2.4.so": /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20:**

Answer (score 18):

Did you build SQLite from source? You forgot to enable Column metadata, compile with

```
CFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1" ./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Enjoy!

Reference - https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_column_metadata

Comment: Medal for this gentleman! This comment has saved me hours of wondering what I had missed.

Comment: Is that a typo? Should it be `CFLAGS="-SQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA=1"` ?

Comment: @monkey honestly, I can't recall at the moment.

Comment: @monkey I looked and it's not a typo.

Comment: I spent a long time figuring out why my Lua library wasn't working. After opening it in IDA, I noticed it was using 3 specific functions, after a quick google, I ended up here. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Installing different version of GDAL on Ubuntu didn't solve the problem.
I noticed that the library is working well on MacOS, So I Installed Linuxbrew and then I installed GDAL via Brew, now it is working like charm.

```
1- http://linuxbrew.sh/
2- sudo apt-get remove gdal-bin
3- brew install gdal
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Anaconda you could try this:

```
conda update sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Ganesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62947251/8248123) answer. In my case OpenCV used gdal, and gdal was referring to sqlite3. I had to rebuild sqlite3, and gdal as well. Then, on top of that, the rebuild of OpenCV library was also required. All of this was I guess because the brand new build libraries were added to the different directories than the original ones.